# Arranging five letters of the word MISSISSIPPI

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking for some help with the following two questions, I have included my explanation for part a but I am not sure if it is correct or how to do part b, thanks!

Question a) how many ways are there to arrange the letters in MISSISSIPPI?

Explanation 1)

The word MISSISSIPPI has $11$ letters, not all of them distinct.

There are $\dbinom{11}{4}$ ways to **choose** the slots where the four S's will go. For **each** of these ways, there are $\dbinom{7}{4}$ ways to decide where the four I's will go. There are $\dbinom{3}{2}$ ways to decide where the P's will go. That leaves $1$ gaps, and $1$ singleton letters, which can be arranged in $1!$ ways, for a total of 
$$\binom{11}{4}\binom{7}{4}\binom{3}{2}1!.$$

Explanation 2)

In general if you have n objects with ${r_1}$ objects of one kind, ${r_2}$ objects of another,...,and ${r_k}$ objects of the kth kind, they can be arranged in

$$\frac{n!}{(r_1)!(r_2)!...(r_k)!}$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{11!}{4!4!2!}$$

Question b) How many arrangements are possible using $5$ letters from MISSISSIPPI?

Comment: Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857187/arranging-the-word-mississippi?rq=1).

Comment: your last answer is right it is a Permutation with repetition

Comment: Both of your explanations are correct for the first question.  However, your second question is incomplete.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/669719/28900) seems to be related. As does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/158755/28900).

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner is my first solution right?

Comment: I wasn't sure if the solution I gave for a was actually the solution for b and I had the switched

Comment: What is the question in (b)?  The statement of the question is incomplete.

Comment: no your first solution is not right

Comment: By the way, your two approaches to part (a) get the same answer, just by a different approach.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  Of course, it is right.

Comment: ok then the Solution is right

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sorry I just edited that question, could you help me with that now?

Comment: and can you tell me why? probably a proof or so?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  We have eleven positions to fill.  We can fill one four of them with an I in $\binom{11}{4}$ ways, four of the remaining seven positions with an S in $\binom{7}{4}$ ways, two of the remaining three positions with a $P$ in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways, and the final position with an M in $\binom{1}{1}$ way.  Notice that $$\binom{11}{4}\binom{7}{4}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1} = \frac{11!}{4!4!2!1!}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig what about question b?

Comment: ok that helps, i have not saw it

Comment: @fr14 Please check my edit.  Did you mean how many permutations are possible using $5$ letters from MISSISSIPPI?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yeah I believe arrangements and permutations are the same thing aren't they?

Comment: @fr14 Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig no problem, would you be able to help now?

Comment: @fr14 I am writing a solution.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the comments, both of your explanations for the answer to part (a) are correct.

> How many arrangements are possible using five letters from MISSISSIPPI.

The number $5$ can be partitioned in $7$ ways.
\begin{align*}
5 & = \color{red}{5}\\
  & = 4 + 1\\
  & = 3 + 2\\
  & = 3 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 2 + 2 + 1\\
  & = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1\\
  & = \color{red}{1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1}
\end{align*}
However, the word MISSISSIPPI does not contain five copies of the same letter, nor does it contain five different letters, so we do not have to worry about the first and last cases.

*One letter appears four times and a different letter appears once*:  There are two ways to pick which letter will appear four times, I or S.  There are $\binom{5}{4}$ ways to choose the positions of that letter.  There are three ways to select the letter that will fill the remaining position in the word.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{4}\binom{3}{1}$$

such arrangements.

*One letter appears three times and a different letter appears twice*:  There are two ways to pick which letter will appear three times, I or S.  There are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to select where in the word it will appear.  There are two ways to choose which letter will appear in the remaining two positions, P and the letter not selected earlier from the set $\{I, S\}$.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{1}$$

such arrangements.

*One letter appears three times and two other letters each appear once*:  There are two ways to choose the letter that appears three times.  There are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to choose the positions for that letter.  There are three ways to pick the letter that will fill the leftmost open position.  There are two ways to pick the letter that will fill the remaining open position.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}$$

such arrangements.

*Two letters each appear twice and one letter appears once*:  There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to pick which two letters appear twice from the set $\{I, P, S\}$.  There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose the positions of the selected letter that appears first in an alphabetical list and $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose the positions of the other selected letter.  There are $2$ ways to pick the letter that fills the remaining open position.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}$$

such arrangements.

*One letter appears twice and the other three letters each appear once*:  There are three ways to choose the letter that appears twice from the set $\{I, P, S\}$.  There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose its positions.  There are $3!$ ways to arrange the remaining letters in the remaining positions.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{2}3!$$

such arrangements.

Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the desired answer can be found by adding the above results.

Comment: so then the final answer will be $\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{2}3!$

Comment: @fr14  The final answer is obtained by adding the results for the five cases stated above.

Comment: so then $\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{4}\binom{3}{1} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{1} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1} + \binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1} + \binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{2}3!$

Comment: @fr14 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: reading back through this explanation again and it really helped me to understand, thanks again!!

Answer (score 5):

You've already solved part (a), in two different, equally viable ways. As for part (b), I'd proceed by cases, depending on how many repetitions there are.

- No letter can be repeated five times. (Do you see why?) Also, at least one letter must be repeated. (Do you see why?)
- If there is a letter repeated $4$ times, then there there are $5$ places to put the other letter. Given such a choice of placement, there are $2$ choices for the repeated letter, and $3$ choices for the non-repeated letter. How many arrangements does this give?
- If there is a letter repeated $3$ times, then there are $\binom52$ places to choose where other letters must go. As before, there are two ways to choose the letter that is repeated three times. Now there are two subcases to address: one with another repetition, one with no others. Once the thrice-repeated letter is chosen, there are two ways to have a "full house" (that is, to have a different letter repeated twice). On the other hand, if no other letters are repeated, then once the repeated letter is chosen, there are $\binom32$ ways to choose the remaining two letters, and then $2!$ ways to arrange them. How many arrangements do these subcases this give? Adding them together will give the total number of arrangements with a letter repeated three times.
- If there are two distinct letters repeated twice, then there are $\binom32$ ways we can choose which letters are repeated, then $2$ choices for the non-repeated letter, and $5$ places we can put the non-repeated letter. Then, there are $\binom42$ places to put the two repeated letters that come first in the alphabet, at which point, the other two repeated letters are assigned places by default. How many arrangements does this give?
- If there is only one letter that is repeated, and that letter is repeated exactly twice, then there are $3$ choices for which letter is repeated, and $\binom52$ ways to place the repetitions. At that point, we already know what the three non-repeated letters must be. (Do you see why?) Since there are $3!$ ways to place the three non-repeated letters, how many arrangements does this give?

Now, as there are no other possibilities, and as we've counted mutually distinct possibilities in each case, just add up the results, and you'll have your answer.